# angular ui-grid expandable table is extremely buggy or just me?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am following the tutorials line for line, I can't provide snippets or screen shots because its work related and our machines have no internet sorry ><

anyways, Ill try to explain. Lets say I have 4 rows and any number of columns, this fits nicely on my UI. Once I add ui-grid-expandable, I have 8 rows..

The first 4 rows just have the plus symbol, and underneath are my actual rows, its super buggy and looks messed up. If I click the plus it will show the sub table but in between both the plus symbols and the actual rows, its unusable.

I have tried release 20 and unstable but no difference.

I noticed when I remove all my CSS such as bootstrap, the table all fits together and I get 4 rows, but when I click the expand button the table is again all wonky. If I have 3 columns in the sub table, and 1 row, the first 2 columns in the row get populated but the third column is blank, and a new row is created juts for the third value, but it is placed under the first column

I could use some advice / examples ..sorry for no pics and code snippets.

```
<div class="grid" ui-grid="data" ui-grid-expandable></div>
```

its basically this code http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_expandable_grid ... you can get the plnkr there but for some reason plnkr is not loading for me. I am pretty much copying the tutorial.

Comment: Could you mock it up on plnkr.co so we can at least get some idea of the setup you're doing here.

Comment: yes i also tried some basic example and yes its unstable. I prefer using the old friends such as jQuery Datatables or sencha extjs Datagrid both have good documentation and lot of function.

Answer (score 0):

Angular UI-Grid expandable table is still in Alpha stage. The main issue here is their Grid isn't able to auto calculate the height, which results in subGrid over-writing the main grid elements when the height reaches max point.

I've made a small work around that might be helpful. It uses the TreeLevel calculation that triggers both the main grid and subGrid in autocalculating the heights.

```
onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.treeBase.on.rowExpanded($scope, function(row) {
        if( row.entity.$$hashKey === $scope.gridOptions.data[50].$$hashKey && !$scope.nodeLoaded ) {
          $interval(function() {
            $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(51,0,
              {name: 'Dynamic 1', gender: 'female', age: 53, company: 'Griddable grids', balance: 38000, $$treeLevel: 1},
              {name: 'Dynamic 2', gender: 'male', age: 18, company: 'Griddable grids', balance: 29000, $$treeLevel: 1}
            );
            $scope.nodeLoaded = true;
          }, 2000, 1);
        }
      });
```

And then we need to make the loop through data and set the height once we receive the data in this way.

```
$timeout(function(){
      if (!!$scope.gridOptions.data) {
          $('.ui-grid-render-container-left .ui-grid-viewport').height($('.ui-grid-render-container-left .ui-grid-viewport').height() + 17);
          $('.ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-viewport').addClass("no-horizontal-bar");
      }
   });
```

My Plnkr [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lSKXblyuocn3VD1gffri?).